# Why setNavigationBarHidden:animated: change bounds and frame my subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I have problem with hiding/showing navigation bar. I push my view controller without nib
and create view:

```c
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.photoView = (UIImageView *)self.view;
    [self nextPhoto];
}
```

PhotoView (self.view) have all space on screen and i add pinch, pan and tap with image.
If make single tap, need show or hide navigation bar:

```c
- (void) toggleNavigationBar:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)aGestureRecognizer
{
    // for debug
    CGRect bounds = photoView.bounds;
    CGRect frame = photoView.frame;

    // toggle navigation bar
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden animated:YES];

    // for debug
    CGRect bounds2 = photoView.bounds;
    CGRect frame2 = photoView.frame;
}
```

For example, i zoom in image x2 and then tap to show navigation bar, then my vars changed:

before:

```
bounds = origin=(x=0,y=0) size=(width=320,height=480)
frame  = origin=(x=-160,y=-240) size=(width=640,height=960)
```

after:

```
bounds2 = origin=(x=0,y=0) size=(width=160,height=240)
frame2  = origin=(x=0,y=0) size=(width=320,height=480)
```

image zoomed back and then all manipulation with image work wrong.

Why it happened and how fix it? I think problem in hidden property,
and i need use opacity instead hidden property.

Comment: I rewrite code with using alpha property of navigation bar and now all work good. But with using hidden property it still problem.